# Delete website in Magento can't delete store and store view

Tags: magento

I have a controller extended from `Mage_Adminhtml_System_StoreController`, below is the action I overwrite:

```
public function deleteWebsitePostAction()
    {
        $multiWebEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/multi_web_general/multi_web');
        $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');

        if (!$model = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($itemId)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->__('Unable to proceed. Please, try again'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        if (!$model->isCanDelete()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->__('This website cannot be deleted.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/editWebsite', array('website_id' => $model->getId()));
            return;
        }

        $this->_backupDatabase('*/*/editWebsite', array('website_id' => $itemId));

        try {
            $model->delete();

            if ($multiWebEnable) {
                $websiteCode = $model->getCode();
                $websiteDir = BP . DS . 'mpshop' . DS . $websiteCode;
                if (is_dir($websiteDir)) {
                    $objects = scandir($websiteDir);
                    foreach ($objects as $object) {
                        if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                            if (filetype($websiteDir . DS . $object) == "dir") {
                                rmdir($websiteDir . DS . $object);
                            } else {
                                unlink($websiteDir . DS . $object);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    reset($objects);
                    rmdir($websiteDir);
                }
            }

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('core')->__('The website has been deleted.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, Mage::helper('core')->__('Unable to delete website. Please, try again later.'));
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/editWebsite', array('website_id' => $itemId));
    }
```

I tried to comment out this function in my controller but the issue still there.

I'm confused with this. I need to know why this can happens, give me some suggestion... THanks

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

After research deep inside, I realise one foreign key was missing between `core_website` table and `core_store`, `core_store_group`.

The solution here is download Magento Database Repair Tool which available to download at Magento homepage.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that deleting websites can only be done from admin panel which is why the standalone script has that.

( Placed in root/var folder )
This will delete your website from a standalone file:

```
require_once( 'app/Mage.php' );

umask(0);
Mage::app( 'admin' );
function deleteWebsitePostAction()
{
    try 
    {
        $sWebsiteId = 'a';
        $oWebsite = Mage::getModel( 'core/website' )->load( $sWebsiteId );
        if( !empty( $oWebsite->getId() ) )
        {
            $oWebsite->delete();
        }
    } 
    catch( Exception $oException ) 
    {
        Mage::logException( $oException );
    }
}
deleteWebsitePostAction();
```

To implement this in the admin panel ensure that you are submitting the correct variable to the controller, in this case I chose the name website_id so your form should have an  somewhere.

```
public function deleteWebsitePostAction()
{
    try 
    {
        $sWebsiteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam( 'website_id' );
        $sWebsiteId = 'a';
        $oWebsite = Mage::getModel( 'core/website' )->load( $sWebsiteId );
        if( !empty( $oWebsite->getId() ) )
        {
            $oWebsite->delete();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_getSession()->addError( 'Unable to proceed. Please, try again' );
            $this->_redirect( '*/*/' );
            return;
        }
    } 
    catch( Exception $oException ) 
    {
        Mage::logException( $oException );
        $this->_getSession()->addError( 'Unable to delete website. Please, try again' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not really helpful. I use Magento DB Repair Tool and this problem fixed, the only one reason that I'm unable to delete websites is one foreign key missing. Btw, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Disable your cache from Admin> System> Cache management
Refresh your cache and check again. 
You can also delete your cache from cache management or [root]/var/cache